# Initializing a Variable for Strings Using Ternary Operators in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf, conditional-operator

So I want to set strings as my variables' value which is dependent on some other test cases.

```
        const char* trial_1;
        const char* trial_2;
        const char* trial_3;


        trial_1 = (pref_A != pref_B) ? "AB" : ((pref_A != pref_C)? "AC" : "AD" ) ;
        trial_2 = (pref_B == pref_C) ? B : ((pref_B == pref_D) ? B : C);
        trial_3 = (pref_B == pref_C) ? C : ((pref_B == pref_D) ? D : D);

        printf("%s/%s/%s", &trial_1, &trial_2, &trial_3);
```

However, the problem is that when I run the test cases for my code. I got this as the output

```
trying "swimmeet 1 1 1 1"
d/P/@/
```

Instead of this,

```
trying "swimmeet 1 1 1 1"
A/B/C/D
```

This suggests to me that I'm printing the memory address instead of the value inside of the address (correct me if I'm wrong).

Running it on vscode, I got this issue:

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix this.

I've tried not using const char * and use char <variable_name>[] instead, but the issue still persists

EDIT: [image]

so this is the output of the program now after I run with make

Comment: `printf("%s/%s/%s", &trial_1, &trial_2, &trial_3)` is wrong.

Comment: `((pref_B == pref_D) ? D : D)`... The obfuscated, pointless result of making "ternary" the priority... Don't write unclear, pointless code like this. Make "clarity" your religion, not some arbitrary other pursuit...

Comment: I have to do this because I'm doing this for one of my machine problems for my uni course this semester and the professor wants us to print a string value based on test cases using fewer than 5 "if" statements @Fe2O3

Comment: In addition to the obvious syntax hiccup of `%s` and `&variable`, the warning "pointer from integer without a cast" also suggests that you probably meant "B" instead of B. Visual C being an ancient C90 compiler still using "implicit int" nonsense. Update to a compiler from this millennium or at least from year 1999.

Comment: @user23569449 What Lundin proposed is correct. It seems, based on your expected printf result, you wanted ```"B"``` and not ```B```. The same goes for ```C``` and ```D```.

Comment: would you kindly give us a minimally reproducible example of your problem ? Right now we have to assume the type of `pref_B`, `B`, `pref_C`, `C` …

You could for instance remove the other tests but keep the definition of the variables used so that we can know better how your error is related to what you have. 

Then, we would be able to give you a definitive answer with more detailed explanations.

Comment: Hint: Change `printf( "%s/%s/%s"...` to `printf( "A" "/%s/%s/%s"...` since 'A' seems to be a constant. Then the "B", "C" and "D" can jockey for other positions (with the missing 3rd `'/'`)... Uniformity makes code easier to read and understand. (Edit: you can then switch from `%s` to `%c` and assign to `char` variables instead of `char *` variables.)

Comment: Please show error messages as text, not as picture.

Answer (score 0):

You printed the address of strings and not their contents.
use this line:

```
printf("%s/%s/%s", trial_1, trial_2, trial_3);
```

Note that `printf` looks for a NULL-terminated string started at addresses *trial_1*, *trial_2*, and *trial_3* when you set with `%s`.